# while creating case record through vf page, i want to give option to add attachment before saving case record

Tags: visualforce, case, attachment

I have a requirement where user should have option to add attachment before saving the case record. Currently i am creating a case using visualforce page. 
please suggest how can i achieve this?

Vf page to create case record:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="AutoPopulateExample">

    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:pageBlock >

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
              <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
              <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons> 

           <apex:pageBlockSection title="Basic Details" columns="2">
               <apex:inputField label="Contact Name" value="{!Case.ContactId}" >
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!autoCal}" reRender="form"/>
               </apex:inputField>
               <apex:inputField label="Requestor First Name" value="{!Case.Requestor_First_Name__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField label="Account Name" value="{!Case.AccountId}"/>
               <apex:inputField label="Requestor Last Name" value="{!Case.Requestor_Last_Name__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField label="Status" value="{!Case.Status}"/>
               <apex:inputField label="Requestor Email" value="{!Case.Requester_Email__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField label="Subject" value="{!Case.Subject}"/>
               <apex:inputField label="Requestor Contact Number" value="{!Case.Requester_Contact_Number__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField label="Product" value="{!Case.Products__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField label="Business Impact" value="{!Case.Business_Impact__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField label="Components" value="{!Case.Componet__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField label="Business Urgency" value="{!Case.Business_Urgency__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField label="On Behalf of" value="{!Case.On_Behalf_of__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField label="Environment" value="{!Case.Environment__c}"/>
               <apex:inputField label="Description" value="{!Case.Description__c}"/>
           </apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSection title="Attachment Details" columns="2" id="block1">


    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="File Name" for="fileName"/>
      <apex:inputText value="{!attachmentObject.name}" id="fileName"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="File" for="file"/>
      <apex:inputFile value="{!attachmentObject.body}" filename="{!attachmentObject.name}" id="file"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="Description" for="description"/>
      <apex:inputTextarea value="{!attachmentObject.description}" id="description"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

  </apex:pageBlockSection>    
    </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public class AutoPopulateExample
{
public Contact con{get;set;}
public Case caseObject{get;set;}
public Attachment attachmentObject {get; set;}
public ApexPages.StandardController stdCntrlr {get; set;}

public AutoPopulateExample(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    con = new Contact();
    caseObject = new case();
    caseObject = (Case)controller.getRecord();

    this.stdCntrlr=controller;
     this.attachmentObject = new Attachment();
}

//function is called from actionsupport event

public void autoCal()
{

Id conid = caseObject.ContactId;     // collecting contact id from visualforce page

List<Contact> conLst = [select id,AccountId,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone from contact where id=:conid];

    if(conLst.isEmpty())
    {
      return;
    }


caseObject.Requestor_First_Name__c = conLst[0].FirstName;      
caseObject.AccountId = conLst[0].AccountId; 
caseObject.Requestor_Last_Name__c = conLst[0].LastName;
caseObject.Requester_Email__c = conLst[0].Email; 
caseObject.Requester_Contact_Number__c = conLst[0].Phone; 


}

    public PageReference save() {

        // Save the Case
        PageReference pr = stdCntrlr.save();

        // Save the Attachment using the Case id as the parent Id
        attachmentObject.ParentId = stdCntrlr.getId();
        insert attachmentObject;

        // Go wherever the standard controller wnts
        return pr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [apex:inputFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputFile.htm) for this as illustrated in [Uploading an attachment using inputfile tag](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130511/uploading-an-attachment-using-inputfile-tag/131690).

So in the `save` method, first save the Case, then set the Id for that Case as the ParentId of the Attachment and save the Attachment.

Assuming you are using the StandardController `save` method, the changes would be something like this in the page:

```
<apex:inputfile value="{!attachmentObject.Body}" filename="{!attachmentObject.Name}"/>
```

with controller changes of:

```
public with sharing class AutoPopulateExample {

    ...
    public Case caseObject {get;set;}
    public Attachment attachmentObject {get; set;}

    private ApexPages.StandardController sc;

    public AutoPopulateExample(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {

        this.sc = sc;
        ...
        this.attachmentObject = new Attachment();
        ...
    }

    public PageReference save() {

        // Save the Case
        PageReference pr = sc.save();

        // Save the Attachment using the Case id as the parent Id
        attachmentObject.ParentId = sc.getId();
        insert attachmentObject;

        // Go wherever the standard controller wnts
        return pr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Keith thank you for response.
I have made the changes in code as suggested. but it is showing me below error on vf page.

"Unknown property 'CaseStandardController.attachment'"
I am not able to add code to show you.

Comment: i have corrected that error and getting vf page as expected. but when i try to select contact name (lookup on case) it is giving me error "apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute. "

Comment: @SnehalGaware I don't know what your problem is. I suggest you persevere for a couple of hours trying to figure it out (Google is your friend) - you have a fairly explicit explanation of the problem in the error message you get. If you remain stuck post a new question with your full page and full controller and an exact copy of the error message.